# KnockoutJS visible binding not working in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel with the following computed observable:

```
var showBackNavArrow = ko.computed(function () {
    if (questionIdx() === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}, this);

// Elsehwere in the file....
var questionIdx = ko.observable(0);
```

and the following in my HTML:

```
<td>
    <button title="Click to view previous question" id="previous" class="previous" data-bind="visible: showBackNavArrow">Previous</button>
</td>
```

In IE7, when viewing my web page, the above button is never shown even though the computed observable returns `true`.

In IE8+, Chrome and FireFox the button is displayed.

Why does the "visible" binding not work in IE7 here?

EDIT:

I'm using KnockoutJS version 2.1.0.

Comment: Which version of knockout are you using?

Comment: Updated the question to include KO version.

Comment: I can only try this in IE7 emulation from IE9 but it seems OK in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/morgantiley/F7thm/

Comment: Is IE7 reporting any errors? If you can reproduce this in jsFiddle, that would help a lot.

Comment: No errors are being reported to the console window.

Comment: Your posted code works just fine in IE7 ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/tR8dn/)), so you need to give us more to go with. jsfiddle is your friend

Comment: OK, I might have to return to this later. I have another IE7 issue to deal with :( I hate it when clients insist on using old, out of date, browsers. Such a waste of time.

Comment: @jason Evans did you find a solution for this i am havng the same issue!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816185/rendering-issues-with-ie-7-web-page#comment20755562_14816185

Comment: @anna Let me have a look tomorrow when I'm at work, as I don't recall right now. I haven't touched the code in a couple of months. I will let you know at around 9 - 10am GMT.

Comment: @anna I've checked this morning, and can confirm that we did not solve the problem in IE7. Luckily for us it's not a massive priority (at the moment anyway) to resolve this. One tip - have you tried posting your question on the KnockoutJS groups on Google? I think they have have Google group where the KO devs respond to questions. Worth a shot. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: thanks jason i ll take a look there

Answer (score -1):

Please, try to wrap visible with single quotes in ViewModel:

```
<td>
    <button ... data-bind="'visible': showBackNavArrow">Previous</button>
</td>
```